# Converting NULLs in relational algebra

Tags: relational-algebra

I have a table as a result of an outer join, I want to SUM on an attribute but some tuples are NULL in that attribute. How would one go about converting NULL into an appropriate value (in this case 0)?

The book I'm reading doesn't really dwell too much on the NULL type in relational algebra, so I'm going to assume that the aggregate functions doesn't try to do the "right thing" and interpret null as Unit.

Comment: What book? An "extended relational algebra" is not a standard thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I solved it. The trick is to use the extended projection operator along with selection and union.

In my particular case we wanted to convert nulls into 0s, here we go:

Assume relation R

R - select(q = null, R) union project(pn, 0 -> q, select(q = null, R))

On the LHS of the union we remove all occurrences of q = null from R.
On the RHS we take all tuples where q = null and project them as pn and all q-column values are 0.

The union in bag semantics can be thought of as plus.

Comment: You are correct, but then it is better to use `q is null` instead of `q = null` since the last condition is always false. And if you use the extended projection (see for instance [this](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/aut07/slides/ra.pdf)) then you could do this with just a single projection, assuming that you have a case-like operator.

Comment: It is true that in SQL you can't do an equality check with null as I did above but there's nothing that makes that incorrect in ERA. There's unfortunately no case-like operator!

Comment: But are you using some specific system with ERA as language?

Answer (score 1):

In the relational data model, a `NULL` value is not an ordinary value, and is not converted to any particular value according to different operators.

SUM, as the other aggregate operators, ignore NULL values, so in fact summing a column with null values is equivalent to sum all the non-null value, and this is, obiously, equivalent to treat `NULL` as `0`. In the same way, if you try calculate the average of a numeric column, only the non-null values are summed up and than the total is divided by the number of non-null values (not all the values).

On the other hand, if you want to consider a null value in a special way for some operation, you can check for it and substitute it with the value you are interested in.

For instance, the following SQL query calculates the `AVG` of non-null values of `column`:

```
SELECT AVG(column)
FROM table
```

while the next one calculates the `AVG` considering `NULL` values as `0` (and so giving a result which is different from the previous one):

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN column IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE column END) 
FROM table
```

Comment: This would be entirely correct in SQL but I'm talking about extended relational algebra, hence my confusion. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Relational Algebra is studied mostly to give a semantics to the relational data model, and to show how SQL expressions can be transformed in order to be optimized. The extended version, in particular, has operators like aggregations, not present in the original one, to model more closely the SQL semantics, so that for instance it works on bags instead of sets. And almost always it is discussed in books without reference to NULL values. So, actually I think the question is more appropriate for SQL then for relational algebra.

Comment: I invite you to re-submit the question for SQL instead of relational algebra and post your answer there.

Comment: PS. How exactly would you discuss outer joins without the notion of null in extended relational algebra?

Comment: You are right, I was referring to the single table operators, but of course the outer joins are defined for the cases of null values.

Answer (score 0):

You may use MySql's [IFNULL()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html) function:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(IFNULL(possibleNullValue, 0)) 
FROM 
    table
```

`IFNULL()` will check if expression 1 is null and, if so, take the value you provided as the second expression - in this case `0`.

If you're not using mysql, see equvivalents for other DB engines [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)